# How to publish artifact from local jenkins to local nexus - both on docker containers?

Tags: maven, docker, jenkins, nexus

I want to publish an artifact from Jenkins on my machine to nexus on my local machine. In the future these two will have dedicated servers, but currently, for testing purposes I want to try it that way.
Jenkins and Nexus are in separate containers.
I am able to publish to nexus from my machine, running `mvn clean deploy` from project root directory.
I cannot do it using Jenkins.
When I enter container with Jenkins using: `docker exec -it jenkins-container bash` and doing `curl http://localhost:8081` I receive message

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8081: Connection refused

As I understand I need to provide different url than `localhost`, but which? How can I find it? How to configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two docker containers must be on the same network. Once done, you can communicate with each other through their name that will become host :

example : curl http://{docker_container_name}:8081

See the documentation to implement a network in docker :

https://docs.docker.com/network/

Comment: I've added two containers to my network and running `curl http://{docker_container_name}:8081` results in no message now. Something has changed. I still couldn't publish. This time with result `Return code is: 400 , ReasonPhrase:Bad Request.`. Will look further.

Comment: If you have an error 400 it means that your two containers can now communicate well together. Now it's another problem, I do not have enough information to answer it

Comment: I changed it from `http://{docker_container_name}:8081` to `http://{docker_network_container_ip}:8081` and it worked :) Thanks! Could you update your answer? To obtain containers IP use `docker network inspect name-of-net`